# Python C# Library BLS

Tags: python, c#

This is the statement in python for importing a a class into another class.

```
from .aggregation_info import AggregationInfo
```

The converter has transformed the above code into c# as follows.

```
using AggregationInfo = aggregation_info.AggregationInfo;
```

But this is generating the following error:

```
Severity    Code Description    Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'aggregation_info' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  BLS12_381.Net   C:\Users\shahe\source\repos\BLS12_381.Net\BLS12_381.Net\keys.cs 18  Active
```

Need to have the resolution

Comment: where is `aggregation_info.AggregationInfo` defined? Did you add a reference to the assembly containing that type in your csproj-file?

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the `C#` compiler cannot find the namespace or type named `aggregation_info`.

Make sure that the `AggregationInfo` class is defined in a namespace called `aggregation_info` in your C# code. In `C#`, `namespaces` and `classes` are case-sensitive, so they should match exactly.